# Create SQL Table from Random Array for WebService

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, select, create-table

I have this little project that I'm working and I got to a part where I want to do something specific but can't seem to figure out a solution that works. Basically I've created a Web Service in Visual Studio that is used for a mobile app and we wanted to add a new piece of functionality that allows the retrieval of clients from multiple users. To do this I need to be able to pass an array of values to a WHERE IN clause, which I've been finding out is pretty much not possible but the other solutions I've read (that have no real example of the process) is to create a table of the Array values and then to a WHERE IN (SELECT * from TEMPTABLE) type of scenario.

So this is where I'm stuck, how do I go about passing an array of values to my SQL statement that will then create a temp table of those values (can range from 1 to 30 values) so then I can run other queries against those values. Most of the examples I've seen have the temp table hard coded with values, but I need to be able to pass an random amount of values for that table, so if it's easier to pass them as one single string with commas is fine or if they need to be passed in a specific format I can do that as well on the iOS side before calling the Web Service, I just can't seem to figure out how to do this dynamic type of table to move on to the next portion.

**EDIT (Adding some information based on Comment)**

So some background information on the system and purpose to help get a better understanding of what I'm doing. The Database is a SQL Server (2008) with already existing tables and data since what I'm working on is a Mobile Application port of an existing Web Application. Two tables that I can use for example are an Agent table (for employees) and a Customer Table (for their client) and so in some cases we have Teams that can view each other's clients. So normally if I wanted to pull a list of clients from a group of agents I would use the WHERE IN statement, but for the Web Service it would need to take that group as a Variable since the Rep may want to see only a few team members or all team members (this would be an option set in the iOS App).

I don't really have code that works, and most of what I have tried I know doesn't really work so I'll put some pseudo code to explain what I want to do. At first I thought I could just do this:

```
SELECT C.first_name + ' ' + C.last_name as [Client Name]
FROM dbo.agent as A INNER JOIN
dbo.contact as C ON C.agent_id = A.id
WHERE (A.id IN (@RepList))
```

In this example, @RepList would be a string passed from the iOS App to the Web Service that contained all the ID's that were selected within the Application. As I've looked into this, I can't have a variable in a WHERE IN statement but I've read that if I create a Temp Table with the variables then I could reference it like this:

```
CREATE TABLE #TempTable (TempID VARCHAR(MAX))
INSERT INTO #TempTable (TempID)
VALUES (@RepList)

SELECT C.first_name + ' ' + C.last_name AS [Client Name]
FROM dbo.agent AS A INNER JOIN
                    dbo.contact AS C ON A.id = C.agent_id
WHERE (A.id IN (SELECT #TempTable.* FROM #TempTable))
```

So again, @RepList would be the list of ID's that are passed from the iOS Application over to the Web Service that will run this query. This is where I'm stuck, since I can't seem to figure out how I can pass a list of values as a Variable into the TempTable. This may end up just being an issue in Visual Studio (since I've had issues with the SQL Query Designer and it not accepting certain things that end up working in the WebService) but I want to be sure this is the right format of doing so before moving forward. In the end, the WebService needs to be able to return a list of Clients based on however many Agents the person wants to see (this can range from just 1 agent to 20 agents).

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish with this specific query?  What platform are you on?  What is in your database and how is it structured?  What is some sample code of what you have tried so far?

Comment: Added some additional information to hopefully clarify what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Show us the WebService code that you already have.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are on SQL Server 2008 and VS2010, probably the best solution is to use a Table-Valued parameter.  This link ([here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163%28VS.110%29.aspx)) describes how to use them from a .Net client.

The basic idea is, your webservice code will call a procedure, function or parametized query on SQL Server, where one of the parameters is a table of values.  Then the SQL code will use that table-valued parameter as its source matching table instead of a temporary table.